# C++ initialize objects with packed array of integers

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
#define MYNUM 4
class myClass {
  private:
    char myData[MYNUM];
  public:
    myClass(char myArr[MYNUM]) {
      for (int i = 0; i < MYNUM; i++) myData[i] = myArr[i];
    }
};
```

I want to initialize an array of `myClass` objects like so:

```
static myClass obj_arr[5] = { {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5, 5} };
```

But I am getting `error: too many initializers`. Is there a way that I can initialize the `obj_arr` array in the way that I want?

Comment: This code is [NOT](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c167891eaf698b12) a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When I fix the obvious typos, I get [error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'MyClass'](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3179df7fdca5d87).

Comment: You can't initialize class objects like that, not to mention that you are treating a 1D array like 2D.

Comment: @MooingDuck I've fixed the example in the description.

Comment: @machine_1, the purpose of this question is to ask if it's possible to initialize an array of objects whose constructors take an array of integers as arguments.

Comment: @tedx `myClass`'s constructor doesn't accept an array; it accepts a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

First, in your existing constructor, the `char myArr[MYNUM]` parameter is the same as passing `char myArr[]` which is the same as `char *myArr`. IOW, the constructor takes a simple pointer as input, so it does not actually ensure the input array is really `MYNUM` elements.  To do that, you need to pass the array by reference instead of by pointer.

As for the kind of initialization that you want, add a constructor that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as input.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>

class myClass {
  private:
    char myData[MYNUM];
  public:
    myClass(char (&myArr)[MYNUM]) {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < MYNUM; ++i) myData[i] = myArr[i];
    }

    myClass(std::initializer_list<char> myList) {
      for (size_t i = 0; (i < myList.size()) && (i < MYNUM); ++i) myData[i] = myList.begin()[i];
      for (size_t i = myList.size(); i < MYNUM; ++i) myData[i] = 0;
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/t66yXH)

Comment: Interesting alternative: [`struct myClass { char myData[MYNUM];};`](https://ideone.com/i7CBOp)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an array as a function parameter like that.  You do have a few options to get the initialization syntax you want though:

#### Make `myClass` an aggregate by making `myData` public:

```
constexpr size_t MYNUM = 4;
class myClass {
  public:
    char myData[MYNUM];
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5517e25ceed8f241)

C++ allows the members of aggregate classes to be initialized directly using brace-initialization.  This is the path that the standard library's `std::array` template uses.  This obviously won't work if your class has other data members that you want to keep private.

#### Use a `std::initializer_list<char>`

```
constexpr size_t MYNUM = 4;
class myClass {
  private:
    char myData[MYNUM];
  public:
    myClass(std::initializer_list<char> myList)
    {
        // Initialize first elements of myData with the parameters passed
        for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(myList.size(), MYNUM); ++i) {
            myData[i] = myList.begin()[i];
        }
        // Fill out any missing elements with 0
        for (size_t i = myList.size(); i < MYNUM; ++i) {
            myData[i] = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d638363b6d758d0d)

This will work to initialize a private class member, and it supports brace-initialization.  It even zero-fills trailing elements if not provided like the default way C++ treats brace-initializing arrays.  Its only drawback is that it won't produce an error if *more* elements are given than `myClass` wants.

#### Templates

```
constexpr size_t MYNUM = 4;
class myClass {
  private:
    char myData[MYNUM];
  public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    myClass(Ts... args)
      : myData{static_cast<char>(args)...}
    {
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/796454bb7015963c)

This is the closest you can get to the aggregate initialization approach with a private class member.  Instead of accepting a container to use to initialize `myData`, `myClass`'s constructor accepts a variable number of parameters, and uses them to directly initialize `myData`.  This will zero-initialize trailing elements if less than `MYNUM` parameters are provided and will produce a compile-time error if more than `MYNUM` parameters are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Utilized nested for loop to assign elements of array (which was passed by const. ref.) to member variable.

```
#include <iostream>

#define MYNUM 4

class myClass {
    private:
        int myData[MYNUM][MYNUM];
    public:
        myClass();
        myClass(const int (&myArr)[MYNUM][MYNUM]){
            for(int i = 0; i < MYNUM; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < MYNUM; j++){
                    myData[i][j] = myArr[i][j]; 
                }
            }
        }
        void printmyData(){
            for(int i = 0; i < MYNUM; i++){
                std::cout << "{";
                for(int j = 0; j < MYNUM; j++){
                    std::cout << myData[i][j];
                }
                if (i < MYNUM){ 
                    std::cout << "}";
                    if (i < MYNUM-1){
                        std::cout << ",";
                        std::cout << " ";

                    }
                }
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
};

int main () {
    int mainArr[MYNUM][MYNUM] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {8, 7, 6, 5}};
    myClass obj = myClass(mainArr);
    obj.printmyData();
    return 0;
}
```